# LEGO Scalextric?

Tags: part-identification, electronics

I have a couple of these car parts in my collection but cannot find anything about them. They are copyright 2003 and show a number 3213 on the back axle.

Interesting is that they have 3 electrical connectors on the underside that suggest it gets power from a track of sorts.  Something like LEGO scalextric.

Can anyone shed some light on what this is and how it worked and was controlled?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like this:

[image: Electric, Motor Rechargeable 4 x 8 x 1 2/3 (Track System)]

Which can be found in [set 8364](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8364-1&name=Multi%20Challenge%20Race%20Track&category=%5BRacers%5D%5BTrack%20System%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) only. It's recharged by pushing the car on a charging track piece, itself powered by batteries:

[image: Track System, Energizer Track 16 x 15 x 2].

Not particularly good, but the sheer number of track parts in the set makes it interesting to buy for some people.